# .aggregate() on 2 collections mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Here is the 1st Schema:**

```
const ProSchema = new Schema({
_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
Cv: {Fonction: {Pro: {type: Boolean,},
             Secretaire: {type: Boolean}
}
})
```

**Here's the second Schema:**

```
const CabSchema = new Schema({
Pro: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProSchema' }],
InfoCab: {
    Nom: {type: String}
});
```

**Creating a cabinet:**

```
var cabinet = new cabModel({
_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
InfoCab:{Nom: "Clinique Toto"} //This is the Name of the Cabinet
}); 
cabinet.save((err, cabinet) => {
```

**Creating pro1:**

```
var pro1 = new proModel({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    Nom: 'ProTITI',
    Cv:{ Fonction: { Secretaire: false}}
});
pro1.Cabinets.push(cabinet._id);
pro1.save((err, cabinet) =>  { });
```

**Creating pro2:**

```
var pro2 = new proModel({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    Nom: 'Pro_TOT',
    Cv:{ Fonction: { Secretaire: true}}
});
pro2.Cabinets.push(cabinet._id);
pro2.save((err, cabinet) =>  { });
```

**Creating Pro3:**

```
var pro3 = new proModel({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    Nom: 'Josianne',
    Cv:{ Fonction: { Secretaire: true}}
});
pro3.Cabinets.push(cabinet._id);
pro3.save((err, cabinet) =>  { });

cabinet.Pro.push(pro1, pro2, pro3);
cabinet.save();
```

**The purpose of this question is the following:**

**How can fetch a Pro of type Secretaire from Clinique Toto**.

So far I tried with this:

```
db.Pro.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        Cv: {
            Fonction: {
                Secretaire: true
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "Cab",
         localField:"InfoCab.Nom",
         foreignField: "_id",
          as: "PK"
    }
}
```

But I'm stuck with the last bit: from Clinique Toto.

Cheers,

Comment: I want to have an answer if anyone's around.